# get value from a ModalDialog in Google Sheet using getElementById returns null. What can I do?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a selection from a Modal Dialog in order to paste the selected value in Google Sheets, but I get a *null*

First of all, I execute the ModalDialog with a buttom from GoogleSheets, then I select one option from the drop-down-list. Finally, I just get an empty cell.

I have the following .gs code:

```
//Showing the ModalDialog in Sheets
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Netsuite_menu')
          .setWidth(300)
          .setHeight(50);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
          .showModalDialog(html, 'Select a pay method');
selection();
```

Then in a separated .gs file

```
//Getting value from html selection
function selection(sel){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("selection_");
mainSheet.appendRow([sel,1]); //It just paste the '1'
}
```

And this is the Netsuite_menu.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <style>
     .button {
       background-color: indigo;
       color: white;
       padding: 2px;
       border: none;
       border-radius: 3px;
     }
   </style>
   <script>
        function runIt(){
        var sel = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
        google.script.run.selection(sel);
      }
  </script>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
    <select id="tipo" name="selection" onchange="runIt()">
      <option value="default" disabled selected>-- Select a pay method--</option>
      <option value="driversA">Op. 1</option>
      <option value="driversB">Op. 2</option>
      <option value="business">Op. 3</option>
      <option value="pay">Op. 3</option>
      <option value="pex">Op. 4</option>
    </select>

    <button
    id="btn"
    class="button" 
    value="Accept" 
    name="LoginButton"
    onclick="google.script.host.close();">
    Accept
    </button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe this error shown in Chrome Console helps to understand the specific(s) error(s):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgf7Z.png)

Comment: In your script, when `showModalDialog()` is run, `selection()` is run. By this, the empty value is appended. Is this related to your current issue? And, when the dialog is opened and select one of the options, I think that the value is appended. How about this?

Comment: Exactly, I think that's what is happening, but I don't know how to order the script for geeting the selected value.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `I don't know how to order the script for geeting the selected value.`, in your script, when the option is selected, the value is appended. How about this?

Comment: Yes, I got the appended value since the moment that `selection()` runs. I think that that it executes before to rethrieving the selected value :(

Comment: Actually, it's exactly what I need, however I modified as your html code, but it's still null

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script when the button is clicked, the value is appended to Spreadsheet. I deeply apologize for this situation. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, although I'm not sure about your current script, when `selection();` is still be using, the empty value is appended. Please be careful about this.

Comment: I just add the error by the Chrome console, maybe this can help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. In order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide your current script for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I just shared it to you. Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to append the value of the selected option of the dropdown list when the accept button is clicked.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your HTML side is modified.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <style>
     .button {
       background-color: indigo;
       color: white;
       padding: 2px;
       border: none;
       border-radius: 3px;
     }
   </style>
   <script>
      function runIt(){
        var sel = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
        console.log(sel)
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => google.script.host.close()).selection(sel);
      }
  </script>
  <body>
    <form id="form">
    <select id="tipo" name="selection">
      <option value="default" disabled selected>-- Select a pay method--</option>
      <option value="driversA">Op. 1</option>
      <option value="driversB">Op. 2</option>
      <option value="business">Op. 3</option>
      <option value="pay">Op. 3</option>
      <option value="pex">Op. 4</option>
    </select>

    <button
    id="btn"
    class="button" 
    value="Accept" 
    name="LoginButton"
    onclick="runIt()">
    Accept
    </button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

- If you don't want to close the dialog when the accept button is clicked, please modify `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => google.script.host.close()).selection(sel);` to `google.script.run.selection(sel);`.

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)